# Unexpected value shows in Pandas mean function when reading files

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with csv data. When I used pandas to read the csv file and find the average value, it comes with an extra number to begin.

right answer: 87.98
when I printed: 97    87.98

97 is the first entry of the data (at A1). All the numbers are in the table from A1 to A100 without header and number columns.

why does it happen? How can I remove the 97 part?

```
file = pd.read_csv("malnutrition.csv")

meanD = file.mean()
print("\nPeople with malnutrition's IQ average: " + str(meanD))
```

And also, how can I show the data? Like View in R

Thank you

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the format of the csv?

Comment: this possible means the first value is in a different column
please print the file to inspect the structure of the dataframe

Comment: It thinks that `97` is your column heading. Try `pd.read_csv("malnutrition.csv", header=None)`

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.mean()` returns a **`Series`**, where the Index are the column labels of the original DataFrame and the values are the means of those columns. Even though `file` is a 1-column DataFrame you'll still return a Series, because a 1-column DataFrame is **not** a Series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, 100))
print(df.mean())
 0    5.32
#|    |
#|    Mean of column `0`
#|
#Col label
```

Instead use `Series.mean()` which returns a scalar.

```
print(df[0].mean())
 5.32
```

---

But you have a few other issues with your data. You're reading the first value as the header, which you don't want. In addition there's no need for a DataFrame when you only have one column. So you want

```
s = pd.read_csv('malnutrition.csv', header=None, squeeze=True)  # Should be a Series
print(s.mean())
```